# Cygwin install - difference between Keep and Retrieve

Tags: installation, cygwin

I've tried to search for an explanation about the difference between "Keep" and "Retrieve" while selecting packages for a Cygwin installation, but couldn't find any

Can someone here explain this difference?

A bit of context: I have a running version of Cygwin on my workstation and need to start another one for an offline installation on a remote machine with no access to interenet. I want to make sure that all necessary files are present in the offline instllation directory

[image: Keep vs Retrieve]

Comment: Keep will not change the current state of the package. i think the retrieve option will download the package files to your cache directory, but not install them. The currently installed version is 7.79.1-1. The default action is checked, i.e. install version 7.81.0-1. Install always leaves the package files in the cache folder. Everything is installed under the cygwin root folder. Everything that was downloaded to do the install in in the download cache. The download cache is cummulative. Files are updated, but never deleted.

Comment: Edit: s/in in/is in/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dough, that makes sense. Love the creative edit too :)